# perf annotate doesn't always give output

Tags: ubuntu, profiling, ubuntu-9.10, perf

I am using perf tool in linux. I don't usually get an output when I do 'perf annotate' ! . If I do 'perf report' then I do get the desired report.

I could successfully get the annotate output for my code only once ! and now it keeps giving me a blank output.

Apart from that, I couldn't really install perf so i did make and I could run ./perf? would this be a source of problem ?

Can you please advise me ?

Thank you

Comment: did you compile your code with -g? Did you moved your source file in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today as well... It seems to come from corrupted perf caches. I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.

Removing the caches helped for me:

```
rm -r ~/.debug/
```